# NSDateFormatter dateFromString: returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having problems with `NSDateFormatter`'s `dateFromString` method.

I have the following date: `Tue, 12 Jul 2011 20:18:26 GMT` , but `NSDateFormatter` doesn't seem to recognize it and returns `(null)`.

Here's what I tried:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Tue, 12 Jul 2011 20:18:26 GMT"];
    [dateFormatter release];

    NSLog(@"Date: %@",date);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you need to set `dateFormat` to match the format of the date in the string. Try following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddd, dd MMM YYYY HH:MM:SS ZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Tue, 12 Jul 2011 20:18:26 GMT"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS"];
NSString *newFormattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"Date: %@ || %@",datem newFormattedDate);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that `ddd`?  The [documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) seems to imply that it should be `E`, `eee`, or `ccc`.

Comment: not sure, just made the analogy in length. The format was in pseudo code .)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your date format `@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS"` doesn't match your date string `@"Tue, 12 Jul 2011 20:18:26 GMT"`. You need to use a different date format.

Comment: Okay - what should it be though?

Comment: @David: Take a look at Eimantas' answer. That's a pretty good idea of what you need.

Comment: Yes, I found it. Posted the previous comment before he posted his.

Answer (score 2):

The string you are parsing does not match the format string that you set on your `NSDateFormatter`.  The format you entered is:

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS
```

...which matches strings like:

```
"15/07/2011 10:30:01"
```

If you want it to match `Tue, 12 Jul 2011 20:18:26 GMT`, then you need to change the format.  You might have better luck with:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, dd MMM yyyy HH:MM:SS z"];
```

You may find this [needlessly complex documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) helpful.

Comment: Okay - what should it be though?

Comment: @David - Try `E, dd MMM yyyy HH:MM:SS z`.

Comment: Tried it - but this is still returning `null`.